# Sublime Text Pretty JSON: pretty_on_save not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've just reinstalled [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON) which works fine with `OS X: cmd+ctrl+j`. I'm just unable to make it work with "pretty on save", even though the default `pretty_on_save` setting is true.

```
{
    "use_entire_file_if_no_selection": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "sort_keys": false,
    "ensure_ascii": true,
    "line_separator": ",",
    "value_separator": ": ",
    "keep_arrays_single_line": false,
    "max_arrays_line_length": 120,
    "pretty_on_save": true,
    "validate_on_save": true,
    "brace_newline": true,
    "bracket_newline": true,
    // Default: False
    // Valid Options: False, start, minimal
    "reindent_block": "minimal",
    // Name or Path to jq binary
    // Example: /usr/bin/local/jq
    "jq_binary": "jq",
    "jq_errors": false,
    "as_json":[
     "Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax",
     "Packages/PackageDev/Package/Sublime Text Commands/Sublime Text Commands.sublime-syntax",
     "Packages/PackageDev/Package/Sublime Text Settings/Sublime Text Settings.sublime-syntax",
     "Packages/PackageDev/Package/Sublime Text Menu/Sublime Text Menu.sublime-syntax"
 ]
}
```

How do I make that work? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the answer but mine stopped working after a little while and I disabled and reenabled the package.

This can be done by going into `Package Control > Disable Package > Pretty JSON`, then the same but `Enable Package`.

Hope this helps, I realise this is 3 months later :/